# Работа с классом Date

Tags: java

Мне по заданию надо сделать сохранения объекта типа Date в файл, а потом востановление этого объекта из файла. Сериализацией пользоваться нельзя.

Так вот. Такая штука не работает: `new Date(date.toString())`. Тогда в каком формате надо сохранять дату, чтобы потом было удобно ее прочитать ?

Comment: Правильнее всего сохранять дату в формат ISO 8601.

Comment: Для передачи данных между компонентами действительно лучше всего использовать ISO 8601, который предоставляет как человеко-, так и машиночитаемый вид даты. С ISO8601, правда, у Java до восьмой версии есть некоторые проблемы, поэтому прикладываю [ссылку](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2201925/2908793) на аналогичный англоязычный вопрос.

Comment: Кроме того, если часовой пояс помнить не нужно, бывает удобно таскать дату в виде long-а (`new Date(date.getTime())`).

Comment: PS. В реальном мире надо забыть `java.util.Date` и использовать Joda Time (до Java 8) или `java.time` (после Java 8).

Comment: насколько я помню в date нет информации о часовом поясе, так что тут  сойдет простое сохранение timestamp'а

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берём `date.getTime()` получаем `long` который является [UNIX Time](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), после восстанавливаем как `new Date(unix)` где `unix` это то самое число.